# What is the best way for css rules name?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

Many ajax calls means you are getting content from different template views. In this case some ids could be repeated. So I am wondering about best logic how to name style rules. 
I am currently deciding between two options:

- Add a prefix to each id. Each selector will look like #templateName-idName
- Wrap each template to a div with template name id. So each selector will start with #templateName #idName

What is your opinion about this. Is it a good idea to sepearate absolutely every id with some prefix?

Comment: If items are *not* unique, simply don't id them.

Comment: genereate a random id for the div ids and that would do the trick

Comment: Use classes to define rules for _sets_ of elements.

Comment: @deceze it is not like they are not unique. But when using jquery, it can happen that some ids repeats without knowing.

Comment: Which means they are... not... unique... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some form of psuedo namespace like prefixes for ids is a good idea to prevent collisions.  From a CSS standpoint you should be trying to create more re-usable/consistent styling rules, and therefore generally avoid the use of ids for anything more than site structural elements and one off fixes.  A combination of explicit class/id markers and combinator selectors should lead to clearer and more maintainable stylesheets.  As far as ids go that would make the combined #container-child convention preferable for the initial namespacing reason and also to emphasize and take advantage of the uniqueness of ids.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when I do heavy AJAX, I have the following rules:

Most scenarios I will only be updating one spot the "content".  If I have sub Ajax calls that need to update widgets etc these don't have to be unique ideas.  You can leverage other DOM elements like append or insert after, etc...

Answer (score 0):

How about using IDs and classes together? Something like:

HTML:

```
<div id="templateOne" class="content">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
<div id="templateTwo" class="content">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#templateOne.content { /* styles */ }
#templateTwo.content { /* styles */ }
```